# wp-admin to a different to a subdomain

Tags: wordpress, cors, wordpress-rest-api, wp-admin

I had a wordpress wp-admin running on a different domain.

In other words `WP_SITEURL = 'https//admin.example.com'` and `WP_HOME = 'https://www.example.com'`

Recently I had the bad idea to updated wordpress to the latest version.

All seems work fine but after I realized that was impossibile add a new post or updated an existing one.

For example when I added a new post (/wp-admin/post-new.php) there were few fetch requests from admin to www:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?who=authors&per_page=100&_locale=user
```

Both of them had the same error:

```
Access to fetch at
'https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/?who=authors&per_page=100&_locale=user'
from origin 'https://admin.example.com' has been blocked by CORS
policy: Request header field x-wp-nonce is not allowed by
Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Looking around I found out that would be easy add a new CORS directive, so promptly added this:

```
add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-WP-Nonce', false);
    return $value;
});
```

Ironically the result was even worst, now I have an infinite requests that fail with 403

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me?_locale=user
...
```

Now I'm stuck trying to understand what's wrong, and if there is any way to solve this issue.

Any help to understand what's happening is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change your site url under: Dashboard>Settings>General ? 
Here is a detailed explanation:

https://wpza.net/cors-policy-request-header-field-x-wp-nonce/

In case the problem still consists, try editing the url paths directly in your database:

**Note, you must create a website (database) backup before trying this one!**

1. **Make a website database backup** (export it, or you could use your hosting provider, Cpanel backup option) and export it to a .sql file in phpmyadmin.
2. Save the file to your PC/Mac, and open it with your preferred editor.
3. Make a quick search (ctrl+f in windows, or cmd+f in mac)  for your old url *admin.example.com*
4. Replace all the search results with your new url: example.com/wp-admin
5. Upload (import) the new database file to your hosting server in phpmyadmin.

If it didn't fix your problem, revert back to your original database file  by uploading your back-up sql database file, or using your hosting's restore database backup option.

Comment: Using direct search-replace in DB backup is a bad idea and it will just make things worse - all serialized data will render broken and you will at least loose some settings. In this case one should use `wp search-replace "https://your-old.domain" "https://your-new.domain"`